# Create bins from spacial data in Python pandas - possibly using groupby, diff, and cut?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm having trouble coming up with a good solution to the problem below.  Please share your thoughts.

I'm attempting to map X,Y spatial data (the physical location of buckets) to categories / groupby object in pandas.  Each bucket has space between them physically so the data points of similar buckets are close, unique buckets have larger spaces between them. Buckets are physically spaced out in two planes X and Y and have differing number of points within them.  Only X will shown below for simplicity:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([0,1,2,6,7,8,12,13,14],columns=['X']) 
df['Xdiff'] = df['X'].diff() #Get Diff


    X   Xdiff
0   0   NaN
1   1   1.0
2   2   1.0
3   6   4.0
4   7   1.0
5   8   1.0
6   12  4.0
7   13  1.0
8   14  1.0
```

*I would like a groupby object whose 1st group is data index locations 0-2, the second is 3-5, the third is 6-8.  Something like below*

```
grp1.index = [0,1,2]
grp2.index = [3,4,5]
grp2.index = [6,7,8]
```

I have attempted cut and groupby with no luck:

```
new_bins = df[ (df['Xdiff'] > 1) ] #Get larger diff values

X   Xdiff
3   6   4.0
6   12  4.0

bins = pd.cut( df['X'], new_bins['Xdiff'])

0            NaN
1            NaN
2            NaN
3            NaN
4    (6.0, 12.0]
5    (6.0, 12.0]
6    (6.0, 12.0]
7            NaN
8            NaN
Name: X, dtype: category
Categories (1, interval[float64]): [(6.0, 12.0]]
```

I appreciate your help.  Thanks!

Update:
I'm now working on adding groups outside of pandas then groupby:

```
groups = []
for d in df['Xdiff']:
    if d < 4:
        groups.append(i)
    else:
        i+=1
        groups.append(i)
df['bin'] =groups

df.groupby('bin').count()
```

And the output:
This works but I believe there must be a better way in pandas.  Thanks!

```
    X   Xdiff
bin     
1   3   2
2   3   3
3   3   3
```

Comment: What do you want your output to look like?

Comment: I would like a groupby object with each of the bins.

Comment: Just to be clear, you don't actually need the intervals, you just want to group the consecutive values together?

Comment: Exactly, group consecutive intervals together.  Apologies that I couldn't articulate it as well; thank you for that!

Answer (score 2):

Let's try using boolean logic on `Xdiff` to create the groups instead:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 12, 13, 14], columns=['X'])
df['Xdiff'] = df['X'].diff()
# Create Bins Based on Where Xdiff is Not 1
df['bin'] = df['Xdiff'].fillna(1).ne(1).cumsum() + 1

# Groupby on new index 'bin'
df = df.groupby('bin').agg('count')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     X  Xdiff
bin          
1    3      2
2    3      3
3    3      3
```

Comment: nice! +1 but i think you can just do `df = df.groupby('bin').agg('count')`? or is there some difference?

Comment: i believe `df.groupby('bin').agg('count')` will produce the same named axis, at least it does on my end

Comment: Absolutely correct. I had `as_index=False` when I was testing around with things. Thanks and updated!

Comment: I like this.  I'll play with it on my real dataset and check as the solution if all goes well.  Thank you for your mindshare here.  The .ne is new to me and you helped out alot.  This looks more pandas and far better than my loop!

Comment: I like your approach, however it isn't working on my real dataset as the values are not exactly 1.  They may vary from .8-1.5 for contiguous data but then the new bucket has a diff of 6-15.   So I think instead of .ne(1) I would change to some < 5 type value.  I'll play with it, if you have a nice means to include that I think I can check this as a solution.   Thanks again!

Comment: Can you update your question to include those varying values? And an example output with less than 5. (If I change my answer to be < 5, then it will no longer match your question as asked or desired output, and thus be confusing for future readers.)